# Getting SOAP error while deploying changes in workbench

Tags: soap, wsdl, workbench

I am trying to deploy certain changes using destructive xml in workbench. I am getting the below error on deploy:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   '/app/workbench/soapclient/sforce.340.metadata.wsdl' : failed to load
>   external entity "/app/workbench/soapclient/sforce.340.metadata.wsdl"

This used to work in the past and I am not sure if this has anything to do with the API version. Can someone help ?

Comment: This is an issue for me at the moment too

Comment: did you try with a lower API version other than 34? That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue for this in GitHub: [SOAP Error on retrieve or deploy actions](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench/issues/669).

From the discussion it sounds like the problem might be intermitent and caching related.

I'd suggest posting your experience into that discussion.

---

As per @Pel's comment, reverting to API v33.0 in workbench avoids the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  As a workaround, I switched to version 33.0 while logging into workbench, deployed it and there were no errors.

Comment: @Pel. Glad you got it via a workaround. I've added that to the answer in case anyone else encounters it.