# SF Workbench - API Version v55 - SOAP Error - Parsing WSDL - Failed To Load External Entity `soapclient/sforce.550.partner.wsd`

Tags: workbench

**Issue**

- As of 08/17/2022 myself and my Development/QA team has been running into an issue with SF Workbench when using API v55.
- We are deploying Service Cloud Voice (SCV) Contact Center with features that are in v55
- The following error is thrown, as soon as you login with your SF credentials

> UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'soapclient/sforce.550.partner.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "soapclient/sforce.550.partner.wsdl"

**Related Past Tickets**

- I found this related ticket in the past when this occurred in API v45

  - [Salesforce- Stack Exchange - API Version 45 Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246795/api-version-45-error)

> Version 45 corresponds to Spring '19, it was not available in production on the moment when this question was opened, but should be available now, since all the production organizations should have already migrated to Spring '19.

- I found this other related ticket in the past when this occurred in API v42

  - [Salesforce - Stack Exchange - API Version 42 Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219479/soap-error-parsing-wsdl)

> I'm seeing the same issue. It can be solved by logging out of Workbench entirely and then re-logging in with the API version set to 41. You have to end the session and start over; you can't change the API version in Workbench settings once you get this error.

- I found this other related ticked in the past when this occurred in API v34

  - [Salesforce - Stack Exchange - API Version 34 Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104094/getting-soap-error-while-deploying-changes-in-workbench)

> From the discussion it sounds like the problem might be intermitent and caching related. I'd suggest posting your experience into that discussion. Reverting to API v33.0 in workbench avoids the problem.

**Temporary Workaround (Not Ideal)**

- The error goes away when I use API v54, though we are required at this time to use v55
- Any estimates on how long this usually takes to resolve?

**Additional Details && Attachments**

- SF Workbench URL I am Using

  - [SF - Workbench - Developer Force](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)

**Screenshot of Issue in SF Workbench using API v55**
[image: SF - Workbench - API v55 - SOAP Error]

**Ticket Not Related/Not Duplicate**

- [SF Workbench - API Version - v55 Not Appearing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381303/sf-workbench-api-version-v55-not-appearing)

  - This question was actually asked by me a month ago, this is a different issue where the dropdown to select API Version in SF Workbench did not have a value of v55 This has been resolved since and was able to select v55 and use the deploy feature as we need without issue

Comment: This question was actually asked by me a month ago, this is a different issue where the dropdown to select API Version in SF Workbench did not have a value of v55

This has been resolved since and was able to select v55 and use the deploy feature as we need without issue

However it has recently broken (past couple of days), where I select v55, login with the appropriate SF Org, then it throws the above error

[SF Workbench - API Version - v55 Not Appearing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381303/sf-workbench-api-version-v55-not-appearing)

@identigral

Comment: Confirm that v55 is still an issue with Workbench. You're right in that it's not an exact duplicate of the previous issue but it's the same root cause - they didn't quite fix it. Complain on github.

Comment: @identigral With the latest SF Workbench, I am able to now select API v56 without issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of **SF Workbench**

- I am able to use **API v56 (Winter '23)** for the **API Version** and click the **Login With Salesforce** button and enter **SF Workbench** without any issue

I am **NO LONGER ABLE** to see the error

> UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'soapclient/sforce.550.partner.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "soapclient/sforce.550.partner.wsdl"